# How to convert double to its upper "tens" integer?

Tags: c#, logic

Quick Question:

I have a double and I want to get its upper "tens" number. For ex:

> `20.1` should give me `30`
>
> `29.9` should give me `30`

I do this:

```
int MyDoubleConvertedToInt = MyDoubleNumber;
int RemainderPlaceHolder = MyDoubleConvertedToInt % 10;
int Remainder = 10 - RemainderPlaceHolder;
int Result = MyDoubleConvertedToInt + Remainder;
```

Can I trust that? Is there a better way and less code?

Comment: Your current code would actually turn 20 into 30.

Comment: @juharr right. It is fine for me to always get 10 as an extra offset and I need it actually

Comment: Just use Noppey's solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Divide by ten and use Math.Ceiling(number) should do the trick.
And obviously multiply by ten again :)

Comment: Be careful with what you want this function to do with negative numbers though, it might/might not do what you want it to do.

Comment: My method should work for 20 as well, Math.Ceiling looks for nearest (upper) value that's greater or equal.

Comment: You could also add double.Epsilon to achieve that, if you prefer my method ;-)